# How can I delete a specific cookie prefix with PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, cookies, grocery-crud

I am using codeigniter / grocerycrud, and when selecting a sort column, it remembers this order giving me the only option to re-sort the other direction (at least within the expiration date). I would like to create a button that deletes only the cookies relating to the sort. So far an example of a cookie would be...

hidden_sorting_4884b0e57a895f932a0a6f5657128eda

... and all of the cookies for sorting start with `hidden_sorting_` so it makes sense to have a clear sorting button. Any ideas on if this is possible? A thorough research into built in features came up empty.

I can delete the full name with jQuery like so...

```
$.cookie("hidden_sorting_4884b0e57a895f932a0a6f5657128eda", null);
```

but having trouble with the prefix selection. In jQuery you can do things like...

```
$('input[products*="hidden_sorting_"]').val
```

if I was looking for input, but getting this in a cookie is what I need.

Comment: For anyone looking for solution in Javascript use the snippet below

`var cookie_nm = document.cookie.split(/=[^;]*(?:;\s*|$)/);`
`//cookies_prefix_to_remove is the cookies prefixes you’d like to remove`
`//Delete all cookie that match the prefix`
`for (var x = 0; x < cookie_nm.length; x++) {`
    `if (/^cookies_prefix_to_remove/.test(cookie_nm[x])) {`
        `document.cookie = cookie_nm[x] + '=-1; domain=your_cookie_domain.com; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/‘;`
    `}`
`}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
<?php
session_start(); ob_start();
function destroyCookies($prefix){
  if(isset($_COOKIE)){
    foreach($_COOKIE as $i => $v){
      if(preg_match("/^$v/", $prefix)){
        setcookie($i, '', time()-3600); unset($_COOKIE[$i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
destroyCookies('hidden_sorting_');
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

You will have to use `ob_start()`, with PHP, to ensure you can set the cookie at any time.

Comment: I was playing around with the use and no go. Any idea on accessing the value of this type of cookie instead? It is very simple, products_model. Each column with its own name.

Comment: Try displaying your cookies, like: `implode('; ', $_COOKIE);` to see if you really have the cookies.

Comment: I do get a list, like: `1; 100; asc; products_upc; ; products_model; 1; 50; asc; price_markup_9; ; ;`...

Comment: Do you see the cookie you are looking for?

Comment: Oh, that's the `products` cookie. I thought those were the names of your cookies. I believe I've fixed the problem. Try it again.